# Function for adding new items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an invoice. Line items are arranged in a table, basically like this:

```
| product name (drop down select menu) | price | quantity | line total |
```

I have this JavaScript file: http://pastie.org/3021944.

If I'm editing an invoice, when I change the product by selecting a different one from the drop down menu, it populates the price field, the line total and the grand total of the invoice. That file also adds new rows with form fields and deletes table rows.

Everything works fine, until I click on "Add a new line" to add a new product to the invoice. But then, only on those added rows, the price and grand total for that new line is not updated, it's just blank.

Comment: can you try the .live("blur", function() {}); and see how that works? It may be that your elements are appended after the events are bound.

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing code, but you probably need to use jQuery's [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (formerly [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) ) to dynamically add your events to new DOM elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to attach your events with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so that dynamically added content is wired up automatically

My firewall is blocking your link, but something like this:

```
$(document).on("blur", ".someSelector", function() {
   //your handler
});
```

if you're using jQuery 1.7, or, if you're on an older version of jQuery, you can use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate(".someSelector", "blur", function() {
   //your handler
});
```

Do **not** use live, since it's deprecated

Comment: `live` isn't inefficient in 1.7, just deprecated. If you look at the jQuery source you'll see that `.delegate` and `.live` are both implemented using `.on` now, so there's no difference in efficiency.

Comment: @mblase75 - ahh - I didn't know 1.7 optimized live like that.

Comment: meh regardless its still best to not use live due to its deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make use of [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Meaning it will be applied on any future control that's being added after setting the event.

**Update**: Seems like live is deprecated (Although implemented in 1.7 as comments state). So Adam Rackis's answer seems to be more suitable.

Comment: `live` is deprecated suggest `delegate` or `on` instead.